# Hibernate and Arithmetic Involving Specific Rows

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate and need to perform a basic arithmetic function on the results. Here's my situation:

I'm storing `odometer` and `fuel` and would like to calculate `fuelEconomy`. But to do that I need to know the previous `odometer` reading, which would come from the previous result. Here's an illustration.

Table:

```
ODOMETER | FUEL
65000.0  | 5.000
65500.0  | 15.000
```

POJO:

```
public class FuelLog {
  private double odometer;
  private double fuel;
  private double fuelEconomy;

  /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

Can I accomplish this with Criteria or would I have to resort to an HQL Query? Or would this be better left to a different layer all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it differently. I would store in the database the start odometer value and I would store how many KMs (or miles) the trip took:

```
START |  TRIP | FUEL
60000 |  5000 | 5.0
65000 | 15000 | 15.0
```

Then, you'd have this as your Java class:

```
public class FuelLog {
  private double start;
  private double trip;
  private double fuel;
}
```

This is the same technique usually done for recording monetary transactions for bank accounts, for instance. The only gotcha is that you must ensure that "start" is always equals to the previous start + previous trip, to avoid gaps and/or inconsistencies.

The idea is that an instance of this class should not depend on other instances to be a valid instance.

Another possible solution, which I don't think is valid in this case, would be to store the "sequence number" in the log, as an index. For instance:

```
START |  TRIP | FUEL | INDEX
60000 |  5000 | 5.0  | 1
65000 | 15000 | 15.0 | 2
```

Then, you'd have a Java class which contains a collection of `FuelLog`, mapped as an indexed list in Hibernate:

```
public class Car {
  private List<FuelLog> fuelLog;
  public double getFuelEconomy(FuelLog log){/* your implementation goes here */}
}
```

`Car` would, then, be the one responsible for calculating the fuel economy for a particular log entry, as it have access to the previous log entries. But then, you wouldn't have the `fuelEconomy` in your `FuelLog`.

Comment: This gave me some good tips. I may put the calculation in the service layer for now. I'm not crazy about calculating something on insert since I could end up having to recalc a lot of rows depending on what was modified. Seems to leave room for error as my db state would be dependent on my app. The 2nd approach is better but I'd prefer to have my Car unaware of the innards of FuelLogs. Maybe I could brush up on my sql and create a trigger.